# Magento 1.9 multi countries multi langues

Tags: magento-1.9, countries, multi-language

I want to configure magento to support multiple countries and languages without creating stores for countries only stores by language knowing that a language can belong to several countries:

Example:
I created a subfolder /de/ which contains an index.php which points to the german language, on the other hand I want to add the country code as follows:
www.website.com/de-countrycode/product-or-category-or-cms-page

Can someone help me on this topic please?